# How to retrieve lost file from IPFS?

Tags: ipfs

Couple weeks ago I try spin up a local IPFS node, publish a file, and were able to access it via publish gateway. I thought the file would have been store by a lots of nodes, so I deleted it from my local machine, now I can't access the file via the ID (`QmNvxsaXqWoLR1NNJpiRXTEo57ptyg3CjSGBrgeyiyFiPm`) anymore.

I noticed that I can still somehow access the data from the webui, but only able to see the raw data instead of the files. Is there any way to retrieve the file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I actually can retrieve this CID via a simple `ipfs cat QmNvxsaXqWoLR1NNJpiRXTEo57ptyg3CjSGBrgeyiyFiPm`:

```
{
  "0x9a39f286e1cd710da14e45ac124e38f2b6242622": "4.705",
  "0x7c981d31b2ab65ce9f9cce49feac9e9e11e8ca64": "0.174481",
  "0xa83cdaaadbb0e01d5de8df4a670947eacbb11f7e": "0.860812",
  "0x445f4b54039cb1f86644351f2ef324c6876f6d76": "0.036128",
  "0x29eab4341629aa1ae5e996f76ea0750548311ecf": "5.4",
  "0xbbccf6cab5b3aec26b0cbc6095b5b6ddbacfd59a": "17.172011",
  "0x33d5ae030cf11723f9b34ecc6fe5cfe00c6dc133": "0.001909",
  "0x03886228bb749eeba43426d2d6b70eba472f4876": "6.8",
  "0x1eb8e88a563fde7b3b8ebbbb0e1ac117c3d80800": "1821.138157",
  "0x62ba33ccc4a404456e388456c332d871dae7ae9e": "0.000145",
  "0x63e62588330657c99ba79139e7c21af0c0db1e7e": "12.560212",
  "0xcd45fdaa6a72740e1d092f458213ff39d3d94a10": "280.592062",
  "0xb92667e34cb6753449adf464f18ce1833caf26e0": "0.647424",
  "0x9a5179e08acf37b3d84c9a0c0d6f3ea2417f9175": "10.097725",
  "0xc43cffc5db578879cc5d0d4cfe07ad514c934d3b": "6.365907",
  "0x34915628fc56ae8ff6684be39462e7ba398164b8": "0.00069",
  "0x47e2bc7475ef8a9a5e10aef076da53d3c446291e": "5.305",
  "0xf432d70c941ebe657ca8cff0b70d1649d5781eea": "0.153823",
  "0xff90d66d41fc97b223e8005dba51635b5d49632b": "0.002298",
  "0x1cf41ad63f67f3e7f8a1db240d812f5392b9a9c4": "6.05013",
  "0xc418aaa0d1e018ded3efc0f72a089519b3d58683": "0.179902",
  "0x7d209486a3562fe406b72d65b3703884c50bac81": "2.191224",
  "0xe782657a1043062087232b3c20c4d25e2a982cb3": "0.110927",
  "0xd998e5a4777e1b47c1441a88bb553cbf16802e4c": "0.095045",
  "0x9f3ef50ea64adad5b33f1f8222760cfbf42007f7": "0.069055",
  "0x40c1efa324fd80329117409c65081f13e7a08a42": "2790.399058",
  "0x9ef8c5ae4a320ef0984695af9a85d07f5be13792": "0.139741",
  "0xf46422c1b6c2135dbca9b55771fd6e7869a8691c": "995.479262",
  "0xf6f3bc09782d3c0df474eb3cec5cac8423bfedf3": "0.00012",
  "0x4f2769e87c7d96ed9ca72084845ee05e7de5dda2": "0.000509",
  "0x92f1e9a52c1a81fdb76ee6477c0c605917cddbe5": "0.811623",
  "0x1e6424a481e6404ed2858d540aec37399671f5e0": "19253.760913",
  "0xc9b2c3a6a8e1896aadcf236b88019c7574d75069": "781.127767",
  "0xb08f95dbc639621dbaf48a472ae8fce0f6f56a6e": "34.704074"
}
```

> I thought the file would have been store by a lots of nodes, so I deleted it from my local machine

It's important to note that data is only stored by other nodes *temporarily if* they access the content themselves. If you want data to live reliably longterm, you can use a pinning service like Pinata, as you're paying them to keep your data pinned.

Otherwise you have to rely on other nodes pinning your data to ensure it remains available.